# QMake gives Untested Windows Version detected error

Tags: qmake

I am running qmake version 2.01a with Qt version 4.6.3

When I try and call qmake from the console and build a solution I get the following error

"Qt: Untested Windows version 6.2 detected!"

Is there any relatively painless way that I can get qmake to work or override this message.

I have tried qmake -Wnone with no luck

Comment: Is it an option to move to a later version, such as 4.8, or 5?

Comment: Not really, I would prefer to stay on the current version but somehow bypass the warning

Comment: Have you looked at this thread: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22187 ?